# Python presentation of a simulated base sequence with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sequence

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6bCu.jpg)I already wrote a function to simulate a random sequence, consisting of the four bases A, C, G, T, with the length of 10^1, 10^2, 10^3, 10^4 or 10^5. The probability for each base is 0,25. I wrote another function, which calculates the relative number of each base in a given sequence.
Now I want to illustrate in a bar chart the relative number of each base (A, C, G, T) for each length (10^1, 10^2, 10^3, 10^4, 10^5) for a random sequence but I am not quite sure how to do it. My first thought is to write a pandas data frame, but I am a little bit confused about how to include my already written functions to it. Maybe you could help me.

Comment: Please include a small example of a sequence, and what exactly you'd like to chart.

Comment: a sequence could be: "GTGCAGTGATTTCCTCGCAGTATTCATTTG". And I want to have a chart at the end which has 4 bars (relative number of each base) for 10^1, 4 bars (relative number of each base) for 10^2, 4 bars (relative number of each base) for 10^3, 4 bars (relative number of each base) for 10^4, 4 bars (relative number of each base) for 10^5.

Comment: I don't understand what kind of chart you're looking for. Perhaps you can attach a fabricated example? (I don't understand the 10, 100, 1000, etc, part)

Comment: You could maybe use the result from your function that calculates the relative number of each base in a given sequence and use [matplotlib to make a barchart](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html)

Comment: Now I added a quick sketch of how I want the chart to look like in the end

Comment: maybe this post maybe similar to your question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931224/adding-value-labels-on-a-matplotlib-bar-chart

Answer (score 0):

If I understad correctly, you wanted to do something like this:

```
pd.concat([
    pd.Series(
        np.random.choice(list('ATCG'), 10**a), 
        name='10^{}'.format(a)).value_counts(normalize=True) for a in range(2,5)],
    axis=1, sort=True).T.plot(kind='bar')

plt.ylabel('normalised counts')
plt.xlabel('sequence length')
```

[image]